# format date from "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" to "MM.dd

Tags: java, datetime

I want to format date from "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" to "MM.dd".
I have following code

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
t = ft.parse(date); //Date is Sep 16, 2015 10:34:23 AM and of type string.
ft.applyPattern("MM.dd");
```

but I am getting exception at `t = ft.parse(date);`

Please help

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: That doesn't look like Javascript to me - that looks like Java. What locale are you in? You haven't specified it in the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor, so it'll use your default locale - try specifying `Locale.US`...

Comment: Why you need to use SimpleDateFormat? Can't u just simple use t.getFullYear() + "." + t.getDay()? Since you already have the date object.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine for me. Are you sure you don't have any other crud in the string?

Comment: Using javascript you may can follow this link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Comment: Could you include the declaration of `t` in the code?

Comment: What is your Exception?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Three possible explanations:

1. your default locale is incompatible with the input date - e.g. it can't understand `Sep` as a month name
2. there's something wrong with the input string, or
3. `t` is the wrong type (e.g. `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`, or some other type altogether), or is not declared.

You should include details of the exception in your question to figure out which it is, but here's a working example using basically your own code, with the addition of a specific `Locale`.

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
java.util.Date t=ft.parse("Sep 16, 2015 10:34:23 AM");
ft.applyPattern("MM.dd");
System.out.println(ft.format(t));
```

output:

```
09.16
```

Comment: Using your code gives me  Unparsable date exception

Comment: @Nishant sounds like a Locale issue - try my updated code

Comment: It indeed was a Locale issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd", Locale.US);
System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: what is Your goal? Question is about PARSING exception

Comment: but the goal of the question is to convert "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" to "MM.dd".

Comment: OK, thats 2nd stage ;)